# How to use command lines in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, command-line, cmd

I m developing a windows application that will use pdf2text pilot software which supports command line. In this application user needs to specify location of the pdf file. I m able to open cmd but could not pass commands to it or somehow my commands are not getting executed.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Diagnostics.Process
Imports System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

Public Class EDCS

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)     Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dlgrslt As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Dim fnames As String() = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
    Dim txtfnames As String

    For i = 0 To fnames.Length - 1
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            TextBox1.Text = fnames(i)
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + " / " + fnames(i)
        End If
        txtfnames = fnames(i).Replace(".pdf", ".txt")
        File.Create(txtfnames).Dispose()

        Dim convertcommand As String = "textextract """ & fnames(i) & """     /to """ & txtfnames & """"

        '/c will exit cmd and /k will keep it open
        'Shell("cmd.exe /c textextract "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ Part 1.pdf" /to " C:\Users\user\Desktop\ Part 1.txt"")

        'SendKeys.Send(convertcommand)
        'SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")

        Dim p As New Process
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        'p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Two Pilots\PDF2Text Pilot"
        'p.StartInfo.Arguments = "textextract "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ Part 1.pdf" /to " C:\Users\user\Desktop\ Part 1.txt""
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute() = False
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        p.Start()
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(convertcommand)

        'Dim process As New Process()
        'process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe "
        'process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"
        'process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        'process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        'process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        'process.Start()

        'process.StandardInput.WriteLine("textextract "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ Part 1.pdf" /to " C:\Users\user\Desktop\ Part 1.txt"")
        'process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit")
        'process.Close()

              Next
End Sub
End Class
```

OS: Windows 7
vb.net developer

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You're passing your command line args to Cmd.exe, you need to send them to the process thru stnd input so cmd.exe will execute it as if you typed it: `p.StandardInput.WriteLine(convertcommand )`

Comment: it gives error 
system.argumentoutofrangeexception

Comment: can you update the code here with any changes you made?

Comment: I updated my code as per your possible solution.

Comment: If i open cmd and just type 
textextract "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ Part 1.pdf" /to " C:\Users\user\Desktop\ Part 1.txt" 

then the pdf file gets converted to text file successfully no matter what dir it is in cmd

Answer (score 0):

OK, here you go, this should work, turns out that pdf2text has a bug in it, but I managed to get it working by passing a couple of blank lines before the command runs and then also adding a wait for the utility to complete before the command prompt closes. You may need to increase that wait for large files I guess. I get some "The handle is invalid" messages in the command prompt and I suspect they are from pdf2text too, but it looks like its safe to ignore them.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim dlgrslt As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        Dim fnames As String() = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
        Dim txtfnames As String

        For i = 0 To fnames.Length - 1
            If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
                TextBox1.Text = fnames(i)
            Else
                TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + " / " + fnames(i)
            End If
            txtfnames = fnames(i).Replace(".pdf", ".txt")
            File.Create(txtfnames).Dispose()

            Dim convertcommand As String = "textextract.exe """ & fnames(i) & """     /to """ & txtfnames & """"

            Dim p As New Process
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = " /k"
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
            p.Start()

            Using sw As StreamWriter = p.StandardInput
                If sw.BaseStream.CanWrite Then
                    sw.WriteLine()
                    sw.WriteLine()
                    sw.WriteLine(convertcommand)
                    p.WaitForExit(3000)
                End If
            End Using
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Sir SeanN, as per your possible solution it gives me same error system.argumentoutofrangeexception

Comment: I've tried it multiple times and it works every time, I cannot get that error, what line do you get the error on? Are you using exactly what I put above or have you changed it?

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The value must be great
er than or equal to zero and less than the console's buffer size in that dimensi
on.
Parameter name: top
Actual value was -1.
   at System.Console.SetCursorPosition(Int32 left, Int32 top)
   at PDF2TextConverter.ConsoleMethods.ClearConsole(Int32 NumberOfLines, Int32 I
nitialCursorTop)
   at PDF2TextConverter.AppStart.Main(String[] args)

Comment: If i open cmd and just type textextract "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ Part 1.pdf" /to " C:\Users\user\Desktop\ Part 1.txt" then the pdf file gets converted to text file successfully no matter what dir it is in cmd

Comment: OK, so you're seeing that in the command prompt window when the pdf2text software runs right? I can't help you with that - it's not an error in your VB.NET code, there's either a problem with your PDF file (try some others and see if they work), or it's a bug in that software.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your VB.NET code on line 20, is the value in convertcommand after the " /k " _exactly_ the same as what you run on the command line? It needs to be exactly the same, spaces, quotes and everything must be the same.

Comment: yes value of convertcommand after the " /k " shows exactly the same as what i run on the command line.
I copied value from convertcommand after the " /k " and pasted it in cmd.
it runs there but through vb it gives error

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR> /k textextract "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Part 1.pdf" /to "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Part 1.txt"
'/k' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR>textextract "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Part 1.pdf" /to "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Part 1.txt"

Progress:
Text from "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Part 1.pdf" has been successfully extracted...
Text extraction has been completed!

Comment: if i remove /k from convertcommand then nothing happens it just shows cmd window. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException error comes only when i put /k in convertcommand

Comment: I fixed the problem in the edited code above - note that pdf2text is no longer supported so you may want to look for something else, although they have made it open-source, so you could actually grab their code here
http://colorpilot.com/load/PDF2Text_source_code.rar
and then use their code directly in your application without having to call the utility at a command prompt.

Comment: Yes SeanN, you may be right but i got alternate solution for my problem i.e. pdf2text pilot software uses pdfmosaic.dll and in help they have given vb code to convert pdf to text using that dll. Thank You All